# Finding all solutions by Grover search(not superposition)

Tags: quantum-computing, quantum-information

When there are multiple marked elements, grover search provides only superposition of them. If I want to find all the marked elements, not superposition, I could try this:

1) Do Grover search, get superposition of t marked element,

2) observe ele space, get one marked element,

3) remove that element,

4) goto 1)

This takes time step $O(\sqrt{\frac{N}{t}}+\sqrt{\frac{N-1}{t-1}}+\dots+\sqrt{\frac{N-t+1}{1}})$.

My question is, can i do better?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54851/24498, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/16612/5038.  
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that the sum $O\left(\sqrt{\frac{N}{t}}+\sqrt{\frac{N-1}{t-1}}+\dots+\sqrt{\frac{N-t+1}{1}}\right) = O(\sqrt{Nt})$.

The quantum query complexity of this problem is indeed $\Theta(\sqrt{Nt})$.

The lower bound can be shown by reduction from the problem of deciding whether the input has $t$ marked elements or $t+1$ marked elements. This problem is very similar to $t$-threshold, and has a lower bound of $\Omega(\sqrt{Nt})$. This can be shown using the polynomial method or the adversary method.